# Blurry Text Rendering on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit

i working on the ios optimization of my current WIP template and i have a strange font problem.

as you can see here:
*deadlink*

the fonts in the topbar / navbar are totally crisp.
All fonts below are blurry. the bar with the add movies button is not transformed or something. the content with the covers is absolute positioned and the covers itself have perspective and 3d transforms.

the special thing is, that this affects only safari for ios. on chrome for android and desktop browsers all looks fine.

**i've tried the following stuff to fix it:**

- increased the font-size and scaled it down
- added webkit-font-smoothing
- added translateZ(0)
- added prespective
- added preserve-3d

nothing worked. i have no more ideas how to fix this problem. any ideas?

**Edit:**

I use the following @font-face rules for my fonts:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bariol';
    src: url('fonts/bariol_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/bariol_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/bariol_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/bariol_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/bariol_light-webfont.svg#bariol_lightlight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Cheers,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Either consider a different font format, from my experience .woff works very well, I had a similar problem once and for the life of me I can't recall what I did to fix it, consider something like the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

If you make sure every browser has its font format set everything should be fine, anything else is just odd.

I'm pretty sure my problem persisted up until one day when some updates rolled in for the various browsers, I remember specifically firefox having issues with the fonts I was using causing flickering and such.

Comment: i edited my question and added my current @font-face code. i use already woff and truetype, as well as  eot and svg.

Answer (score 0):

Oke i fixed it!

The problem was a perspective:1500px on the wrapper itself. i have no idea why webkit on ios renders fonts so blurry when i apply a perspective. if anybody knows more about it, please share your knowledge :)

Comment: Did you remove the `perspective` line to resolve this?

Comment: as far as i remeber, yes. or just add the perspective direclty into the transform statement itself. transform: translateX(40px) translateZ(20px) perspective(1000px);